# parsing this json isnt working showing double

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The following is what is being returned as the json, stored in `data`

```
    {
   "dialogue":{
      "id":"1",
      "backgroundURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/images\/english\/d-backgrounds\/onboard-metro.jpg"
   },
   "dialogueTexts":[
      {
         "dialogueTextId":"12",
         "dialogueTextSpeaker":"1",
         "dialogueTextText":"Hello, Paul! How are you?",
         "dialogueTextAudioURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/audio\/english\/1\/1\/gina_0.mp3",
         "dialogueTextImageURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/images\/english\/people\/female2.png",
         "dialogueTextDialogueID":"1"
      },
      {
         "dialogueTextId":"13",
         "dialogueTextSpeaker":"2",
         "dialogueTextText":"Hi, Anne! I'm fine, thanks. And you?",
         "dialogueTextAudioURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/audio\/english\/1\/1\/l1-01.mp3",
         "dialogueTextImageURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/images\/english\/people\/male14.png",
         "dialogueTextDialogueID":"1"
      },
      {
         "dialogueTextId":"14",
         "dialogueTextSpeaker":"1",
         "dialogueTextText":"I'm well. Thank you.",
         "dialogueTextAudioURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/audio\/english\/1\/1\/gina_1.mp3",
         "dialogueTextImageURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/images\/english\/people\/female2.png",
         "dialogueTextDialogueID":"1"
      },
      {
         "dialogueTextId":"15",
         "dialogueTextSpeaker":"2",
         "dialogueTextText":"It's good to see you!",
         "dialogueTextAudioURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/audio\/english\/1\/1\/l1-02.mp3",
         "dialogueTextImageURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/images\/english\/people\/male14.png",
         "dialogueTextDialogueID":"1"
      },
      {
         "dialogueTextId":"16",
         "dialogueTextSpeaker":"1",
         "dialogueTextText":"Yes. You too! Good-bye!",
         "dialogueTextAudioURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/audio\/english\/1\/1\/gina_2.mp3",
         "dialogueTextImageURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/images\/english\/people\/female2.png",
         "dialogueTextDialogueID":"1"
      },
      {
         "dialogueTextId":"17",
         "dialogueTextSpeaker":"2",
         "dialogueTextText":"Bye! See you later!",
         "dialogueTextAudioURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/audio\/english\/1\/1\/l1-03.mp3",
         "dialogueTextImageURL":"http:\/\/db5mq3uumohzn.cloudfront.net\/course\/images\/english\/people\/male14.png",
         "dialogueTextDialogueID":"1"
      }
   ]
}
```

The following is my script:

```
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {

            alert(data['dialogueTexts']['dialogueTextText'])

            if(data['dialogue']['backgroundURL'] != ''){

                $('#content-container').css('background-image','url("'+data['dialogue']['backgroundURL']+'")');
                alert(data['dialogue']['backgroundURL']);

            }else{
                alert('test');
            }
        });
```

I cant seem to get to the dialogueTexts and it keeps alert the backgroundURL from dialogue and I dont know why its looping around that. What am I doing wrong to be able to get to dialogueTexts on its second interation and then loop through them?

Comment: data['dialogueTexts'] is an array so you can't access 'dialogueTextText' directly. $.each(data['dialogueTexts'] ...)

Comment: but why does alert('test'); never happen? surely dialogueTexts is on the second iteration of the loop¿?

Comment: using `$.each` incorrectly. Should be dealing with the instances of each loop by referencing `key` and `val`. In your case you are looping an object that has 2 keys. Suggest learning how to use `console` logging to get better understanding of your data. Also look at the errors that are thrown

Comment: @Jake , the alert('test') never happen because data['dialogueTexts']['dialogueTextText'] should throw an error

Comment: What is the best way to access backgroundURL then? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming **data** is is all the JSON you posted above, Here is a version, which is perhaps what you want:

```
$.each( data['dialogueTexts'], function( key, val ) {         
       alert(val['dialogueTextText']); 
});

if(data['dialogue']['backgroundURL'] != '')
       $('#content-container').css('background-image','url("'+data['dialogue']['backgroundURL']+'")');
```

Comment: when looping an array, `key` is `index`

Comment: yes, but personally if it's an array using `key` as index argument name isn't very intuitive

Comment: Nor to me.. minimum changes to what OP had already tried, so as not to confuse him.

Comment: That's why an explanation would be appropriate within the answer